# Histogram raster function in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to call this processing function in PyQGIS but I don't find the name of the processing tools that matches with.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Object name of raster toolbar is `mRasterToolBar`. You can get any tool bar using `findChild()` method of main window.

```py
# get toolbar
tb = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QToolBar, "mRasterToolBar")
```

Tools in raster toolbar are active if any raster layer is selected. First, select the raster layer you work using next lines. Before running the following line, be sure that the raster layer has a unique name.

```
raster_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("raster_layer_name")[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(raster_layer)
```

Index of "Stretch Histogram to Full Dataset" action is 3 in raster toolbar

```
# run action for selected/active raster layer    
tb.actions()[3].trigger()
```

Or to be sure correct tool runs, you can use in the following way:

```
for t in tb.actions():
    if t.objectName() == 'mActionFullHistogramStretch':
        t.trigger()
        break
```

Comment: Is this code for qgis 3?

Comment: @Mr.Che Yes, I tried on QGIS 3.8.